# Exclude hash value and match ID

Tags: php, javascript, html

Sorry not sure how to ask this question but I'm trying to match a ID with a image file, however the file names are formatted as:

```
6993b22905d7a4dae0f6e5ff1212a47c-5.jpeg
```

5 been the ID, so how would I exclude the hash value, the - symbol and display the image using the unique ID instead?

```
<img src="images/uploads/6993b22905d7a4dae0f6e5ff1212a47c-5.jpeg"
```

I would like to have something like:

```
<img src="images/uploads/."IGNOREHASH-".$ID.jpeg"
```

Comment: `preg_replace('~[\da-f]{32}-~', '', $str)`

Comment: @zerkms what if the hash contains more or less than 32/33 chars?

Comment: @Fred: as a developer I'm used to solving a real tasks and I prefer to not play "what if" games. For the current task it is a solution, if OP will provide another examples - we will solve another task with another solution.

Comment: @zerkms 10-4. I thought about it after, and you're entirely right. Your suggestion was a good one, and a `quick 'n dirty way` if you pardon my expression ;-) cheers

Comment: @Fred: it's dirty indeed though :-)

Comment: @zerkms Indeed. The OP's gonna have to get his/her hands `dirty` (lol)

Comment: @zerkms I tried `img src="images/uploads/'.preg_replace('~[\da-f]{32}-~', '', $row{'ID'}).'.jpeg"` and wont display the image, inspecting the element it seems its trying to display `1.jpeg`

Answer (score 1):

Just split the string on period and then on hyphen and get the last instance:

```
str.split('.')[0].split('-').pop();
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/tXyLn/6/)

or in PHP, get the content between the hyphen and the period:

```
preg_match('/\-(.*?)\./',$str, $match);
```

Answer (score 1):

Asuming that every image name follows the same format:

```
function getImageId($imageHashedName) {
     return substr($imageHashedName, strrpos($imageHashedName, '-') + 1)
}
```

(Sorry if the syntax is wrong, my PHP is a little bit rusty.)

You would use it in the following way:

```
"<img src='images/uploads/".getImageId($imageName).".jpeg"
```

Comment: Retrieving the image using the hash value really isn't possible, would rather get it via the ID!

Comment: @MickCue So wouldn't this solve your problem? I thought you needed to take the ID out of the whole image name, so that you can include it into the HTML without the hash. Did I misunderstand the question?